# How can I use gets() in a function to assign string in char *ch?

Tags: c, function, pointers, char, gets

How can I write gets(???);
Thank you.

```
void getStr(**temp){
   gets(???);
}

void main(){
   char *ch;
   printf("Enter a string: \n");
   getStr(&ch);
   printf("main: %s\n", ch);
}
```

------ Output ------
Enter a string:
abc
main: abc

Comment: Welcome to SO!  Have you read up on the gets function?  What isn't clear about it?

Answer (score 2):

Never use the `gets` function. It is inherently unsafe, since there's no way to guard against overruns (the user entering more data than you're prepared to accept). In fact, it was removed from the language by the 2011 ISO C standard.

You should probably use `fgets()` instead. It's a bit more complicated to use (for one thing, it leaves the `'\n'` line terminator in the string), but it lets you specify the maximum number of characters to be read.

Your `getStr` function probably doesn't need to take a `char**` argument; a `char*` would do, since it's not going to be modifying the pointer, just reading data into an array to which the pointer points.

You'll need to allocate a `char` array to read the data into. You can either declare an array object:

```
char line[200]; // for example
```

or use `malloc` to allocate the space.

One more thing: `void main()` is incorrect. (Compilers are allowed to accept it, but there is no good reason to use it.) The correct definition is `int main(void)`. If you have a book that's telling you to use `void main()`, it was written by someone who doesn't know the C language very well, and it's likely to have more serious errors.

Take a look at the [comp.lang.c FAQ](http://www.c-faq.com/).